# Error creating bean with name 'Client' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, xstream

Error creating bean with name 'Client' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class.

This error occurs when I try to update xstream dependency from v1.2.2 to 1.4.19. The application is Spring Java 8

I have tried updating xstream lib to latest version 1.4.19 but it fails. Has anyone faced anything similar?

Comment: can you share complete stacktrace?

Comment: and pom/gradle/whatever file manages your dependencies

Comment: and the bean definition/class